# Xamarin - how to center a launch screen image (iOS)?

Tags: visual-studio, layout, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, splash-screen

I'm using Xamarin for Visual Studio, and am getting frustrated trying to do what I would think should be a very simple thing: creating a launch (splash) screen for iOS, that has a single image that is centered on the screen (vertically and horizontally centered).

I'm creating it the recommended way, using a storyboard (other methods, like using an assets catalog, are considered deprecated as of iOS 9). In the storyboard, I have a View Controller, which contains a View, which contains an Image View. In the Properties pane, I've tried messing with the Mode (in Widget tab), and I've tried playing around with contstraints - which I think might be the key, but it is difficult to understand how it all works together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Splash screen in the applications properties (Launch Images). You need to create the image and upload it via that section. I couldn't find anything saying that the use of Asset catalogues are depreciated.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer the recommended approach in iOS9. They now want you to go via storyboard or XIB. Which leads to all sorts of off-center pain and constraints agony. :(